# ASP.NET Core Web API Skip Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm writing an ASP.NET Core web application using a custom basic authentication, based on the following example: 
[ASP.NET Core Web API Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977088/asp-net-core-web-api-authentication)
Now I have an action in my user controller in order to register user. So I would like to pass this method my custom Attribute "SkipAuthAttribute" in order to say, if someone calls this method (action) you have to skip the authenticaion (the user which want to register, has no login).

But the type HttpContext has no ActionDescriptor to get the Custom Attributes of the action

Knows someone, how can I skip the authenticaion by some specific actions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Updated answer:** 
You should try to write code according to framework. Middleware from example are unsuitable for ASP.NET Core MVC. Here is my example:

```
public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<BasicAuthenticationOptions>
    {
        protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            var authHeader = (string)this.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeader) && authHeader.StartsWith("basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                //Extract credentials
                string encodedUsernamePassword = authHeader.Substring("Basic ".Length).Trim();
                Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
                string usernamePassword = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedUsernamePassword));

                int seperatorIndex = usernamePassword.IndexOf(':');

                var username = usernamePassword.Substring(0, seperatorIndex);
                var password = usernamePassword.Substring(seperatorIndex + 1);

                if (username == "test" && password == "test")
                {
                    var user = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("User"), null);
                    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(user, new AuthenticationProperties(), Options.AuthenticationScheme);
                    return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
                }
            }

            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("No valid user."));
        }
    }

    public class BasicAuthenticationMiddleware : AuthenticationMiddleware<BasicAuthenticationOptions>
    {
        public BasicAuthenticationMiddleware(
           RequestDelegate next,
           IOptions<BasicAuthenticationOptions> options,
           ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
           UrlEncoder encoder)
           : base(next, options, loggerFactory, encoder)
        {
        }

        protected override AuthenticationHandler<BasicAuthenticationOptions> CreateHandler()
        {
            return new BasicAuthenticationHandler();
        }
    }

    public class BasicAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationOptions
    {
        public BasicAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Basic";
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
        }
    }
```

Registration at Startup.cs - `app.UseMiddleware<BasicAuthenticationMiddleware>();`. With this code, you can restrict any controller with standart attribute `Autorize`:

```
[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Basic")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
```

and use attribute `AllowAnonymous` if you apply authorize filter on application level.

**Original answer:**
[From documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data)

> Add `[AllowAnonymous]` to the home controller so anonymous users can get information about the site before they register.
>
> ```
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
> using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
>
> namespace ContactManager.Controllers {
> [AllowAnonymous]
> public class HomeController : Controller
> {
>     public IActionResult Index()
>     {
>         return View();
>     }
> ```

Comment: There is no HomeController, I'm not using MVC, but as said Web API. In my case the basic authentication is a custom Middleware (see example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977088/asp-net-core-web-api-authentication ).So it dosen't care about the AllowAnonymous attribuite. I would like to read the attribut of the controller which is been called.

Comment: ASP.Net Core is the same for MVC and Web API.

Comment: I can't get this to compile. The class BasicAuthenticationOptions does not compile. AuthenticationScheme, AutomaticAuthenticate  not available?

Comment: BasicAuthenticationOptions' cannot be used as type parameter 'TOptions' in the generic type or method 'AuthenticationHandler<TOptions>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'BasicAuthenticationOptions' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationSchemeOptions'.

Comment: I think the issue for me is for Core 2.0 > Anyone have any ideas?