# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web-API Authentication for SPA and mobile. Where to start?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to create a SPA with Vue.js which consumes my ASP.NET Core Web-API. I need user authentication with **username and password**. The API will also be consumed by a mobile app (Android and iOS) later on.

I read this: [ASP.NET Core Web API Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38977088/asp-net-core-web-api-authentication)

I am wondering if there is nothing official available? Is Basic Auth even the right approach? I've read some documentation for ASP.NET Web-API using filters, didn't work for Core.

Then I though about implementing token based authentication myself.

I've also read that since ASP.NET Core 2.0 it's better to use services instead of middleware?

I am stuck and don't know where to start. Maybe the approach in the Question above is okay for my needs?! I am not quite sure.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider Oauth and Identity. You can even use something such as Auth0.

Comment: Hi, I think I will use JWT since it also has a official MS implementation for ASP.NET Core

Comment: Nice, if you found my post helpful please upvote thank you